# Antonym for "genetically modified"

Tags: antonyms

What is an antonym for "genetically modified" or "genetically engineered" in the context of biomedical research? Is there a good adjective to describe cells or organisms that were not genetically modified?

Examples:

```
genetically modified and ??? mice  
??? and genetically engineered yeast
```

The word "wild-type" comes to mind but might be misleading, because it excludes naturally occurring mutations. Maybe "native"?

Since "non-GM" comes up - this is for a publication, so an abbreviation has to be explained. And I try to avoid the phrase "genetically modified and non-genetically modified mice".

Comment: .........non-GM.

Comment: You should probably see how other people in your specific field do it. We're probably only going to give you ideas in general use. In the general use direction, I don't see what's wrong with 'non-genetically modified'. Are you looking for its abbreviation? What's wrong with explaining an abbreviation?

Comment: @Mitch I had a look at various texts, and authors usually try to use other constructs, like starting a new sentence to separate the two entities. And if you only use an abbreviation once in a text, it is imho a no-no to introduce it.

Comment: except for mendel and all before him ... untouched and untainted by mankind!  This GM, non-GM, organic etc ... is all tripe!!!

Comment: @lbf In my book, there is a difference between mating two selected dogs and transfecting a dog embryo with specifically designed viral DNA, so the dog will fit into Paris Hilton's handbag. ;)

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, I agree about using an abbreviation once. But in the sense that either you should not use the abbreviation at all in that case, or the abbreviation is parenthetical so that people know you're referring to the usual concept as usually abbreviated. That is, say 'non-genetically modified organism (non-GMO)'

Comment: and to some 'non GM' means no pesticides, only shit for fertilizer and only hoes  ( the farming tool) used on weeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used a good word yourself (emphasis mine):

> The word "wild-type" comes to mind but might be misleading, because it excludes **naturally** occurring mutations. Maybe "native"?

The definition of [**natural**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/natural) has many different senses, but here are some that come closest:

> **8 a** : occurring in conformity with the ordinary course of nature : not marvelous or supernatural · *natural* causes · died a *natural* death
>
> **10 a** : growing without human care; also : not cultivated · *natural* prairie unbroken by the plow
>
> **b** : existing in or produced by nature : not artificial · *natural* turf · *natural* curiosities
>
> **13 a** : closely resembling an original : true to nature

Comment: There are indeed some instances in the databases, where people used "natural" as an antonym to "bioengineered". Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

"**[Non GMO](http://greenerchoices.org/2017/03/07/non-gmo-mean/)**"  (Consumer Reports/ Greener Choices)

> the “non-GMO” claim means animals were not fed a diet containing genetically engineered crops.

See also:
[The Non-GMO Project](https://www.nongmoproject.org/) website.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have edited the question and added context that it is in the field of biomedical research. The O in GMO stands already for organism, but the text specifies the organism, therefore this cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

> ## [Unmodified](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unmodified)
>
> adjective.
>   Not changed in form or character

Comment: Other forms of modification are possible, even in biomedical terminology.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True, but it covers at least a wide variety of situations. Upvote for this, and you can use it together with the twin "genetically engineered".